# Two identical dates in different formats give different epoch times

Tags: javascript, date

The following statement:

```
(new Date("1993-09-01")).getTime() == (new Date(1993,9,1)).getTime()
```

Seems to evaluate to false across both Node, Firefox and Chromium. Why does this happen?

Comment: You can find more information about Date types [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)

Comment: The two "identical" dates are one month apart. `new Date(1993, 9, 1)` is October 1st, 1993. Read the documentation of [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/date#Syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the index for month in the JavaScript Date object starts from 0 (I.E. January is 0, February is 1, so on and so for).

For the statement on the right, new Date(1993,9,1) will result in 'Fri Oct 01 1993 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)' if when I try to console.log() it.

Try running the below code snippet:

```js
const date1 = new Date(1993,9,1);
const date2 = new Date('1993-09-01');

console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);
```

According to the [JavaScript Date object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax), there are multiple ways of instantiating the Date Object. On your question, you have already used 2 of the formats mentioned on the documentation:

1) `new Date(dateString)`
Some accepted formats for `dateString` include 'December 17, 1995 03:24:00', '1995-12-17T03:24:00', and '1993-09-01'.

2) `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);`

Do note that for the second argument `monthIndex`, the documentation stated that months are 0-based, meaning we have to start counting from 0.

> Note: The argument monthIndex is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and December = 11.

Therefore, `new Date(1993, 9, 1)` would mean refer to 1st of October, 1993. You should be using `new Date(1993, 8, 1)` instead.

---

Even then, after making the above changes, the below snippet would print false. Why is this happening?

```js
console.log((new Date('1993-09-01')).getTime() === (new Date(1993,8,1)).getTime())
```

Once again, we refer to this section in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description):

> If at least two arguments are supplied, missing arguments are either
>   set to 1 (if the day is missing) or 0 for all others.

This means that in the case of `new Date(1993,8,1)`, the remaining optional arguments (hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds) are set as 0. Hence, `new Date(1993,8,1)` is equivalent to writing `new Date(1993,8,1,0,0,0,0)`

Comment: I thought Javascript would be ISO 8601 compliant?

Comment: It depends on how you instantiate the Date Object. Allow me to elaborate further on my answer.

Comment: Depends of the time zone where you are. Internally, times work in UTC time. There is not one directly way to especify the time zone when you create the object, but you can handle the output for get the correct output.

Comment: @EduardoGarcia Exactly! Thanks for sharing that too

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- For the [long constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms), the month is 0-based. so `new Date(1993, 9, 1)` is not September but October 1 1993 ***local time***
- For the [one argument constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value), when the string is passed in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, the engine could assume that ***the timezone is UTC or local*** depending on the specs being followed ([ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-corrections-and-clarifications-in-ecmascript-2015-with-possible-compatibility-impact)). So `new Date("1993-09-01").getTime() == new Date(1993, 8, 1)` could still return false if the engine is following ES5 specs:

```js
var d1 = new Date("1993-09-01");
var d2 = new Date(1993, 8, 1);
console.log(d1.toISOString());
console.log(d2.toISOString());
```